# Как передать класс в другой класс?

Tags: java

Есть класс `Person`, я его должен передать в класс `PersonStatus` так, чтобы в нем были все поля класса `Person` и чтобы я мог добавить новые поля, которые относятся только к классу `PersonStatus`.

Мне подсказали, что можно сделать так:

```
class Person{}

class PersonStatus{
  PersonStatus pst = new PersonStatus(Person);
}
```

Но оно ругается

> "Person cannot be resolved"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы вызываете конструктор класса `PersonStatus`, который не объявляли.

Объявите его:

```
PersonStatus(Person person) {
    // Ваши манипуляции с переданным экземпляром класса Person
}
```

И уже в главной программе используйте этот конструктор:

```
Person somePerson = new Person();
// Устанавливаете поля somePerson 
PersonStatus personStatus = new PersonStatus(somePerson);
```

Answer (score 2):

Судя по используемой Вами терминологии (класс... передать в класс...) Вам надо начать с азов. В данном случае передавать надо не класс, а значение, и не в класс, а в метод.

Answer (score 1):

Вам нужно именно передать один класс в другой класс? Так:

```
public Person { ... }
public PersonStatus
{
    private Person person;

    public PersonStatus(Person p)
    {
        this.person = p;
    }
}
```

Или создать класс, в котором были бы все поля, методы,.. другого класса? Тогда это наследование:

```
public PersonStatus extends Person 
{ 
    public void AnyMethod()
    {
        // тут доступны все public и protected поля, методы,... класса Person
    }
}
```

Comment: `public class PersonStatus extends Person`, это правда жесть.

Comment: Ой, точно - это же так в java делается! :)